# The conversion of the varchar value '0000000000000000000' overflowed an int column in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

**error overflow varchar**

```
 Comm = New SqlCommand("select * from CUSTOMERDETAILS where id='" & TextBox2.Text & "' or aliasname='" & Convert.ToString(TextBox2.Text) & "' ", Conn)
        '  Comm.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = TextBox2.Text
        Conn.Open()
        DATAREADER = Comm.ExecuteReaderenter code here
        If DATAREADER.Read Then
            ComboBox1.Text = DATAREADER(1)
            Conn.Close()
```

help me???

Comment: You're passing a string for the value of a numeric column, so the database will have to try to convert it to a number. Presumably some part of that parsing goes wrong if there are more digits than an int could have. You could parse it in your program first, or change the column type to a string type.

Answer (score 0):

Your parameter is a string according to your sql command (surrounded by single quotes).  therefore you shouldn't be converting this value to an integer.

You could also try changing TextBox2.Text to CInt(TextBox2.Text) if it's not a string.